# How to change the bar code in our ZPL code into a QR code?

Tags: barcode, qr-code, zpl

I'm doing a project at a company which produce new species of flowers and plants. The flowers and plants are labelled with small labels. To make the labels, we use ZPL codes. On the labels we use a barecode which gives the data about the plants. My project is to change that barcode into a QR code.
Now we use this ZPL to create the barcode:

```
^XA
^FO100,63^ABB,30,18^FDBRAZIL^FS
^FO600,130^ABB,30,18^FDWK47^FS
^FO50,63^ABB,30,18^FDATHENA^FS
^FO170,20^ABN,30,18^FDCEL1  CELOSIA^FS
^FO170,70^ABN,30,18^FDARGENTEA INTENS^FS
^FO170,110^BY4,2.0,65^BC,100,Y,N^FD0933860^FS
^FO700,130^ABN,30,18^FD1/46^FS
^FO700,210^ABN,30,18^FDA2^FS
^FO700,170^ABN,30,18^FD403^FS
^FO850,160^ABN,20,14^FD50^FS
^XZ
```

My question is, what do i have to change in the ZPL to make the QR code?

Thanky you very much, Guy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
^FO170,110^BY4,2.0,65^BC,100,Y,N^FD0933860^FS
```

should become

```
^FO170,110^BY4,2.0,65^BQN,2,10^FD0933860^FS
```

But - read the information on page 82 of [the manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zplii-pm-vol1.pdf)

Comment: I'll try this thank you, but does this also work on a avery denisson printer AP 5.4 300dpi?

Comment: I know nothing about avery denisson printers.If they emulate Zebras using ZPLII, then it depends on the quality of the emulation.

Comment: FYI, link is now broken. not sure but think the new link is https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Comment: @pcnate : Good catch. I've fixed the link (now directly to the programming manual vol 1). Always a problem linking to external sites. Zebra certainly don't make it easy finding that manual, (or any others) and the reference you provide seems to ba a more comprehensive version (^BQ documentation on P 106 of that tome).